# Accelerometer on XDK not being read on device

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

I'm working on a project in the Intel XDK and using the intel.xdk.accelerometer.watchAccelerometer property.  I have a temporary variable set up to test if the accelerometer has been watched, but it's not firing on my device, based on the test I have set up.

init.js code:

```
/* This code is used to run as soon as Intel activates */
var aX = 0;

//in case necessary
var aY;
var aZ;

var temp = false;

//this isn't firing based on the temp variable's operation on device!

function success(a) {
    aX = a.x;

    //if needed later
    aY = a.y;
    aZ = a.z;
    temp = true;
}

var fail = function() {};

var watchAccel = function() {
    var opt = {};

    //every X/1000 seconds
    opt.frequency = 5;
    opt.adjustForRotation = false;

    intel.xdk.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(success, opt);
};

function onDeviceReady() {
    //lock orientation
    intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation("portrait");
    intel.xdk.device.setAutoRotate(false);

    //hide splash screen
    intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();

    watchAccel();
}

document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

JavaScript load order:

```
<head>
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>         <!-- phantom library, needed for XDK api calls -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>          <!-- phantom library, needed for Cordova api calls -->
<script src="xhr.js"></script>              <!-- phantom library, needed for XDK CORS -->
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/init.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- stuff -->
<script src='js/app.js'></script>
</body>
```

EDIT:  I've gotten it to work once, but about half an hour later, it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/507858) intel.xdk.accelerometer has been deprecated in favor of Cordova's accelerometer.

The [Cordova accelerometer API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html) can be used to check the current accelerometer settings or to set up a callback that is called at specified regular intervals.

To check the current accelerometer values:

```
navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onSuccess, onFail);
```

where `onSuccess` supplies a parameter object with x,y and z values of the accelerometer reading, and a timestamp indicating when that reading was taken.

However, since you refer to `watchAcceleration`, you probably want to use

```
navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onFail, {frequency:250}) ;
```

which has a similar `onSuccess` function to the above and includes an options object indicating how frequently (in ms) at which you want to query the accelerometer.

You can try [this app](https://github.com/xmnboy/hello-cordova) to see a working version of the Cordova accelerometer API, with the accelerometer code [here](https://github.com/xmnboy/hello-cordova/blob/master/www/js/cordova-acc.js).

Comment: Would it work to implement the getCurrentAcceleration function in a setInterval loop?  The watchAcceleration function doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: In theory, yes, assuming that getCurrentAcceleration is working for you, but I notice that cordova has an issue with iOS devices not working properly with getCurrentAcceleration (just uses the last known value).  I don't know if intel.xdk has the same problem on iOS.  You should be able to check the timestamp to be sure that it's a new value.

Comment: Ok, it does work on the emulator, but still doesn't on the device (using the Cordova accelerometer and watchAcceleration function)

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: I'm using an iPhone 4,and emulating on an iPhone 4S, 3GS, and Nexus 4.

Comment: Update:  Everything works EXCEPT for the accelerometer.  The image is being drawn, and it detects what it needs to perfectly.  (excuse me if double-commenting is frowned upon; I'm new to SO)

Comment: Do you mean your app, or the hello-cordova app (https://github.com/xmnboy/hello-cordova) doesn't work?  If the former, can you try hello-cordova on your device and see if that works?

Comment: My app.  I'll try the hello-cordova app; do you know an easy way to get it on besides copy/pasting?

Comment: You should be able to `git clone` it to your workspace then just open as an xdk project, or import it as an existing html webapp